# json input and write back to file php

Tags: php, json

Hello i have fallowing post input data

i am trying to update localize file which is json format
it has 524 Lines, and output is success

```
{
    "loading_js_content":"Loading Javascript Content...",
    "offical_site":"Official Site",
    "Online_users":"Online Users",
    ......
    .....
   ......
and go on

}
```

html

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="lang_file"  class="FormBlock">    
<table class="ranktable">
    <tr class="head" >
        <td colspan="2" id="boxTitle">Edit/Update <?php echo $LangName; ?> Values</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="head">
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $i = 0; 
        foreach($LangData as $key => $value):   
        $i++; 
        $class = ($i%2==0) ? 'alt1' : 'alt2';

    ?>

    <tr class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align:left">
            <input type="text" name="lang_key[]" class="formatted"  value="<?php echo $key; ?>" style="width:150px;"  />    
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left">
            <input type="text" name="lang_val[]" class="formatted"  value="<?php echo $value; ?>" style="width:380px;"  />  
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

1. The problem is when getting post. Count $_POST['lang_key'] is 500 lines instate of 524.24 line is missing affter line 500.
2. How can i write it to file back as same format ? i have fallowing code as far as i can do

```
foreach( $_POST['lang_key'] as   $lang_key => $key)
{
    $data[] = $key;
}

foreach( $_POST['lang_value'] as $lang_value => $val)
{
    $data[] = $val;
}

file_put_contents(BASE_DIRECTORY.'test.json',json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `lang_key` parameters as the keys in the associative array, and `lang_value` as the corresponding values.

```
foreach ($_POST['lang_key'] as $index => $key) {
    $data[$key] = $_POST['lang_value'][$index];
}
```

I don't know why you're only getting 500 inputs, though.

Comment: thanks for fixed write as json format. but still get missied inputs count. When i print out with loop foreach it success. displays whole lines. really weird. Any limit of  getting inputs?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution after some search. The problem is comes from `max_input_vars in php.ini`: its default is `1000`. So when I try to `post 500 -> lang_key and 500 -> lang_value` it's oversize it.

So the solution is `change php.ini -> max_input_vars` to bigger value and no more issues.